# Graphical User Interfaces

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, idioms

Suppose we have a class that stores a list of Student Objects. There is another class that uses a graphical user interface to ask the user to create a student object.

I tried doing something like this

```
public class Database {

    private List<Student> students;

    public Database {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }


    public void addStudent() {
        StudentDialog dialog = new StudentDialog();
        dialog.setVisible(true)
        students.add(dialog.getStudent());
    }

}

public class StudentDialog extends JDialog {

    private JTextField field;

    public StudentDialog(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        field = new JTextField();
    }

    public Student getStudent {
        return new Student(field.getText());
    }

}

public class Student {

    private String name;

    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

However, this does not work as the user takes time to input the student. What is the most idiomatic way of reaching my goal? To be clear, I want to be able to add Students at will using the addStudent method.

Comment: Separate you data management requirements from your interface requirements, it should no difference if your adding from a GUI, command line or some other programmatic API.  Also, what? *"I want to be able to add Students at will using the addStudent method."* - So what's wrong with what you've got?  If it's just you don't want to have to keep typing stuff in, then see the first part of the comment

Comment: This actually does not work. When the addStudent method is called, it finishes before the user enters any data in the text field.

Comment: Call `setModal` and pass it `true` in the `StudentDialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the addStudent method is called, it finishes before the user enters any data in the text field

To make the dialog halt the current execution of your code until it is closed, you will need to make the dialog modal.  Add `setModal(true)` to the dialogs constructor

```
public class StudentDialog extends JDialog {

    private JTextField field;

    public StudentDialog(Frame owner) {
        super(owner);
        setModal(true);
        field = new JTextField();
        // I assume you're actually adding this text field to the dialog
    }

    public Student getStudent {
        return new Student(field.getText());
    }

}
```

You could just use a `JOptionPane` instead

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details